.Net GDI+ - Rotate at a fixed point
I have a need to draw objects at a specific location, but rotated at a specified degree, with the object 'appearing' to the user as still being drawn at the x/y location that was entered.
For example, if a square was rotated 45deg, the very left corner of the square should be at the 'X' location entered.  Simply using a Graphics.RotateTransform(45), and then drawing the square, since it is rotated, the 'left' point will now appear further left than expected.  Rotating the square a full 90 will have the full width of the square to the left of the 'X'.

In the above example, the first row of images are if I simply call 'Graphics.TranslateTransform(x,y); Graphics.RotateTransform(deg);'
The 2nd row is the result I'm looking to achieve
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, 100, 138, 200, 138);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, 300, 138, 400, 138);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, 500, 138, 600, 138);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, 700, 138, 800, 138);

e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(100, 140);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Fuchsia, 0, 0, 100, 20);
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(300, 140);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(45);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Fuchsia, 0, 0, 100, 20);
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(500, 140);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Fuchsia, 0, 0, 100, 20);
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(700, 140);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(315);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Fuchsia, 0, 0, 100, 20);
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

I can calculate the actual width/height of the rectangle after its rotated by:
var deg = 45;
var rad = deg * (Math.PI / 180);
var h = 20;
var w = 100;
var objH = h * Math.Abs(Math.Cos(rad)) + w * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(rad));
var objW = w * Math.Abs(Math.Cos(rad)) + h * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(rad));

But I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to use that, along with the rotation degrees to specify a value in the TranslateTransform call to achieve what I'm looking for.
I did come up with a work-around of drawing to a bitmap, and then just drawing that bitmap at the x/y pos, but this is not a great solution as it is pretty inefficient and in my case the target of this is a PDF document and the image will not be a vector, and therefor will not zoom/scale correctly.  I'll be writing text into these shapes as well, so that also will look poor...  Hack work around:
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, 100, 138, 200, 138);

var deg = 45;
var rad = deg * (Math.PI / 180);
var h = 20;
var w = 100;
var objH = h * Math.Abs(Math.Cos(rad)) + w * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(rad));
var objW = w * Math.Abs(Math.Cos(rad)) + h * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(rad));

var img = new Bitmap((int)objW, (int)objH);
img.MakeTransparent();
var sub = Graphics.FromImage(img);
//sub.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 0, 0, (int)objW, (int)objH);


sub.TranslateTransform(
    ((float)objW / 2f), ((float)objH / 2f), MatrixOrder.Append);

sub.RotateTransform(deg);

sub.DrawRectangle(
    Pens.Fuchsia,
    -(w / 2),
    -(h / 2),
    w,
    h);

sub.ResetTransform();
sub.Dispose();
e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 100, 140);


Squares don't have a very left corner; they have top left and bottom left corners. I can't quite figure out what rule you are following to get the second row of images (particularly the 2 right most images). You may want to add identification to the corners so that the reader can figure out what you are trying to do

When I was referring to the 'left corner', I was referring to the bottom left corner of the square.  Which, after being rotated 45deg, is now further left than the top left corner.

Here's some code that rotates the points of the rectangle using a Matrix:
private int angle = 0;

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    angle = trackBar1.Value;
    this.Text = "Angle: " + angle;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(new Point(100, 140), new Size(100, 20));
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, rc.Left, rc.Top - 2, rc.Right, rc.Top - 2);
    drawRectangleAtPoint(e.Graphics, rc, angle);
}

private void drawRectangleAtPoint(Graphics g, Rectangle rc, int angle)
{
    PointF[] points = rotatePoints(rc.Width, rc.Height, angle);
    int minX = (int)points.Min(p => p.X);
    int minY = (int)points.Min(p => p.Y);
    g.TranslateTransform(rc.X, rc.Y);
    if (minX < 0)
    {
        g.TranslateTransform(Math.Abs(minX), 0);
    }
    if (minY < 0)
    {
        g.TranslateTransform(0, Math.Abs(minY));
    }
    g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Fuchsia, points);
    g.ResetTransform();
}
private PointF[] rotatePoints(int width, int height, int angle)
{
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix M = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix();
    PointF[] points = { new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(width, 0), new PointF(width, height), new PointF(0, height) };
    M.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(0, 0));
    M.TransformPoints(points);
    return points;
}

The program in action:

